# Using cscope when making Linux kernel and cscope.files difference between "allnoconfig" and "defconfig" seems incorrect?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, source

There seems to be very little difference between "allnoconfig" and "defconfig" when using diff to view the separate cscope.files for each build. Is this correct? Both files come out to be 1.5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

cscope doesn’t know about the kernel configuration, it looks at all available C and header files (depending on the arguments you provide when running `cscope`).